# Can you use GLSL shaders with JavaFX 3D?

Tags: javafx, javafx-3d

Is there any way to use your own custom GLSL shaders with JavaFX? I am currently using Java 8 162 and find that there is a serious lack of JavaFX 3D documentation.

Comment: The short answer is no and you are right that there is a lack of documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought as much as I could not find anything documented on it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to use your own custom GLSL shaders with JavaFX?

No. GLSL shaders are compiled at runtime and are bound to the OpenGL graphics pipeline, which is internal. There was a request for this in the past, but no one put in the work for it.

You might be able to hack something in if you build JavaFX locally. It depends on how extensive the changes you want to make are. You can add shaders like the one in `modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/resources/com/sun/prism/es2/glsl/main1Light.frag` (and `main2Lights` and `main3Lights`). You will then need to change `com.sun.prism.es2.ES2PhongShader` accordingly, at the very least.

What shader are you trying to make? Maybe it can be built into JavaFX if it's reasonable.

> there is a serious lack of JavaFX 3D documentation

Yes. Many internal classes have "TODO: 3D - Need documentation" comments on them too. I suggest that you write to the mailing list a request for what documentation you would like to see exactly.